# Android pathPattern not matching file extension

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I'm trying to associate my activity with a particular file extension. Here's my intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="content" 
          android:host="*" 
          android:mimeType="*/*" 
          android:pathPattern=".*\\.jcrlccip" />
</intent-filter>
```

However I'm still not able to match the file type. In fact, this matches nothing.

I've pretty much tried all the permutations. `.*` matches everything; anything after * fails.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What file extension are you using here?
Do you want like PDF or video file or image file?

Example code:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" android:scheme="content"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Its a custom extension `.jcrlccip` (basically a json file with a different extension).

Comment: I don't know why but this works. My data tag is now `<data android:mimeType="application/jcrlccip" android:scheme="content"></data>` ... quite illogical seeing as the mimeType actually is octet-stream ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="*" android:scheme="file"
            android:pathPattern=".*\." />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Nope this doesn't work either. Isn't the escape slash escaped itself?